# Select statamen of a Datarow array

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following code, first I filter by a foreign key, but then with that result I need to filter more with dates.

But I cant understand the syntax of the `select()` method of a datarow array given below.

```
 UC021_WizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_UnitsSelectedInOtherAgreementsRow[] datarows =
                    _uc021_WizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_UnitsSelectedInOtherAgreements.Select(
                        "UnitId = " + row.UnitID).Cast
                        <UC021_WizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.WizardStepSelectUnits_UnitsSelectedInOtherAgreementsRow>().ToArray();

                DataRow[] dr = _uc021_WizardStepSelectUnitDataSet.
                    WizardStepSelectUnits_UnitsSelectedInOtherAgreements.Select(
                        "UnitId = " + row.UnitID);

                if (datarows.Length > 0)
                {
                    dr.Select("");
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select` on DataTable is similar to a Where clause you add to a query, in this case its filtering the records matching the `row.UnitID` which is to be found under column `UnitId` of the DataTable.

You can add multiple conditions by using AND within select like

```
.Select("UnitId = " + row.UnitID+ " AND IsActive='Y'")
```

Comment: thanks, but I am interested in the syntax to use the select method of a Datarow[].